# disabling ssl offloading for IIS ARR and url rewrite

Tags: iis, rewrite

I have a gitea site running sidi by side with my IIS.

I would like to access gitea with regular ports (that is 443).

So I use `ARR` and `Url rewrite` to reach gitea (on localhost:10080) through the port 443 handled by **iis** and iis **default web site**.

It almost works but the certificate seen by the browser is the one of the default web site and not the one used by gitea.

I disabled the SSL offloading expecting IIS to act as a passthrough, but no.

How can I do to transparently (for iis and browser) handle ssl at gitea level ?

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to add a binding to the default web site with the https protocol and then use a certificate at the iis level.